# Objective-C Bug: Wrong IndexPath on Cells with NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using [CardsCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/filletofish/CardsLayout/blob/master/CardsCollectionViewLayout.swift) in my code via Swift Bridging for my CollectionView.

### Objective-C (Not Working)

My issue is that IndexPath is returning wrong `Item` index. Here is the  minimal code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionViewEvents.collectionViewLayout = [[CardsCollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionViewEvents.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionViewEvents.delegate = self;
    self.collectionViewEvents.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.collectionViewEvents.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    [self load];
}

// Issue visible here, the indexPath.item is not correct
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionViewEvents.visibleCells) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self collectionViewEvents] indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"Visible Cell IndexPath Item %ld", indexPath.item);
        return;
    }
}

- (void)load
{

    // self.eventData is declares as: @property (nonatomic) NSArray *eventData;
    self.eventData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:UIColor.blackColor, UIColor.whiteColor, UIColor.brownColor, nil];
    [[self collectionViewEvents] reloadData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCellReuseIdentifier"
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.eventData.count;
}
```

**Result** (notice how both 1st and 2nd cell has same IndexPath Item):

```
2020-03-19 14:48:05.334905+0100 App[7422:2617858] Visible Cell IndexPath Item 2 # => 3rd cell
2020-03-19 14:48:05.741805+0100 App[7422:2617858] Visible Cell IndexPath Item 1 # => 2nd cell
2020-03-19 14:48:06.184932+0100 App[7422:2617858] Visible Cell IndexPath Item 1 # => 1st cell
```

---

### Swift (Working)

I tried [this Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/filletofish/CardsLayout/master/CardsExample/CardsExample/ViewController.swift) from his code Repository, which has declared `colors` statically:

```
  var colors: [UIColor]  = [
    UIColor(red: 237, green: 37, blue: 78),
    UIColor(red: 249, green: 220, blue: 92),
    UIColor(red: 194, green: 234, blue: 189),
    UIColor(red: 1, green: 25, blue: 54),
    UIColor(red: 255, green: 184, blue: 209)
  ]
...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
        cell.backgroundColor = .black

        return cell
    }
```

And after implementing this code below, it returns proper IndexPath.

```
    // Issue NOT visible here, the indexPath.item IS correct
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
            let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
            print(indexPath?.item)
            return
        }
    }
```

**Result**:

```
2020-03-19 14:48:05.334905+0100 App[7422:2617858] Visible Cell IndexPath Item 2 # => 3rd cell
2020-03-19 14:48:05.741805+0100 App[7422:2617858] Visible Cell IndexPath Item 1 # => 2nd cell
2020-03-19 14:48:06.184932+0100 App[7422:2617858] Visible Cell IndexPath Item 0 # => 1st cell
```

What am I doing wrong in my `Objective-C` code?

---

### Things I've tried

```
// 1st cell has index 1, instead of 0
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [[self collectionViewEvents] visibleCells]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self collectionViewEvents] indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"Visible Cell IndexPath Item %ld", indexPath.item);
        return;
    }
```

```
// 1st cell has index 1, instead of 0
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *visible = [self.collectionViewEvents indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [visible firstObject];
    NSLog(@"Visible Cell IndexPath Item %ld", indexPath.item);
    return;
```

```
// Calling it in main thread, same result
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [[self collectionViewEvents] visibleCells]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self collectionViewEvents] indexPathForCell:cell];
            NSLog(@"Visible Cell IndexPath Item %ld", indexPath.item);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: check the answer i think your problem is you are not setting your datasource to you collection view

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen added clarification to your comment and fixed Swift code. I'm not looking to set `backgroundColor` but to get correct `IndexPath.item` with-in Objective-C code.

Comment: Did you try using `[[self collectionViewEvents] indexPathsForVisibleItems]`? It might be the case that indexPaths aren't updated yet, you probably need to enqueue your `for` loop to the end of the main queue (`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ for... })`).

Comment: @AlejandroIván just tried that, check the end of the question. Didn't help.

Comment: Could you maybe try to print the cell itself too when you loop over them? The only explanation I can think of right now is that the visible cells change for some reason while you iterate over them, but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a return inside this loop.

```
for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [[self collectionViewEvents] visibleCells]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self collectionViewEvents] indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Visible Cell IndexPath Item %ld", indexPath.item);
    return; // <- This here
}
```

`visibleCells` returns an array of all cells visible in the collection. You only ever NSLog the first item in that array so it depends on where you scrolled to which one will be first.

Comment: The return has to be there. Same code as with Swift example (which I actually want, to return early on first item). The problem is with wrong indexes on different cards, using same Objective-C & Swift code. See examples I posted again.